# Full extent of a map

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Is there a way to get the full extent of a map? I am looking to use this extent to zoom out to whole world view on a button click.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the full extent of a particular layer can be retrieved by the aptly named 'fullExtent' property.  The value it returns can be passed to map.[setExtent()](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#setextent) in order to accomplish this dynamically if its not sufficient to pass static values to zoom out and view the entire world.

See the API reference for more information
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html#fullextent
https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/arcgistiledmapservicelayer-amd.html#fullextent

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be to use [map.CenterAndZoom](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map.html#centerandzoom) the following:

```
button.on('click', function(){
    var location = [-155.79719, 14.03035];
    //Any location around the equator
    map.centerAndZoom(location, 2);
});
```

A zoom level of 2 will show the entire map.  If you dont want to use this a second option would be to use the [Extent](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/extent-amd.html) class.

Comment: Thanks, this solution worked when I changed the zoom level to 1.

Answer (score 1):

With the 4.x API you just set the **extent** property on the *map view* object.